# phpMyAdmin not allowing access

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

i am using WAMP/ phpMyAdmin but failed to access it :(
it requires a password and giving root username and blacnk password denies access !!!

Comment: have you tried root root? you'll have to be more specific if you want more help.

Comment: i have not tried root root but tried root and blank password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

create a new account then open the config.inc.php from phpMyAdmin directory and made these changes

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

reinstall Wamp might be a solution, i like everything in it's default condition

Comment: for me i cant open phpMyAdmin only, the remaing parts work perfectly.